# How was summoning jutsu created?

Tags: naruto

How did the summoning begin in Naruto?

Summoning was a jutsu that not only required lots of jutsus, but also required a blood contract (probably from a village of animals since all of the summoning animals are sentient).

How was this accomplished when the animals were far away?

Answer (score 2):

According to naruto.wikia.com:

> In the anime, it was shown that if a user attempts to summon an animal without first signing a contract, the user will be teleported to the home of the animal they have a natural affinity for.

Though there doesn't seem to be an explanation as to where it actually originated from/how it began, it would make sense that someone at some point decided that they wanted to summon an animal and attempted it. They were teleported to the home of the animal, where they then made a blood contract with them.

Comment: I don't think that's very accurate. The Third said that there's no way of knowing what could happen. I'm guessing the teleportation would occur in random.

Comment: Yeah. Additionally, the animals are in another dimension. If you don't even know they exist, how would you want to summon them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It was probably created by Hagoromo Ōtsutsuki (Sage of Six Paths). We all know he created Ninshuu and was a monk who travelled and explored.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that the animals where the ones who invented summoning jutsu. We can see that they are capable of using summoning jutsu